# Sending an email from gmail smtp server in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, email

I know how to send an email from local smtp sever in ASP.NET 1.1

And to use gmail server...we need to use we need to provide port number...i.e

we need to use SmtpClient...which is available only after framework 2.0..

I just want to know, whether I am correct in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use SmtpMail in asp.net 1.1, however, it does not have support for ssl directly like in 2.0, you have to set fields. check:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1291908.aspx/1